# Is it possible to get Performance Summery seconds of Chrome DevTools with Puppeteer?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, pagespeed

I want to get the ms per category of Performance > Summery using Puppeteer.

I was looking here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformancePaintTiming and it's possible to get some speed KPIs but I'm especially looking for the time spend with Scripting and Rendering here. Is it possible with Puppeteer to collect these numbers

[image: I'm looking for these ms numbers in puppeteer]

Thanks

Comment: Try sending a raw command [Performance.getMetrics](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance/#type-Metric).

Comment: thanks 'ScriptDuration' seems to be what I was looking for